# A better to deal with 0 when using min-max transform in R?

Tags: r

I want to apply min-max scaling to my data. However, I use `-10` as an indicator of missing value. So I convert all `-10` values into `NA` and when applying the function. This leads to a dataframe of all `NA` values. Hence, I try by applying `na.omit()` first to my dataframe and then apply min-max scaling. This works but I lose all the information of missing value. How can i deal with this problem?

```
min_max <- function(x)
{
    return((x- min(x)) /(max(x)-min(x)))
}

> dput(df)
structure(list(X1.4 = c(-10, 2, 3, 4), X1.4.1 = c(1, -10, 3, 
4), X1.4.2 = c(1, 2, 3, -10), X1.4.3 = c(-10, 2, -10, 4), X1.4.4 = c(1, 
2, 3, -10)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

** Note that I want to apply min-max by columns.

Edit for comment:

```
# new data frame
structure(list(X1.4 = c(-10, 2, 3, 4), X1.4.1 = c(1, -10, 3, 
0), X1.4.2 = c(1, 2, 3, -10), X1.4.3 = c(-10, 2, -10, 4), X1.4.4 = c(1, 
0, 3, -10)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

# desire output: where 999 indicates values after min-max normalization

  X1.4 X1.4.1 X1.4.2 X1.4.3 X1.4.4
1  -10    999    999    -10    999
2  999    -10    999    999      0
3  999    999    999    -10    999
4  999      0    -10    999    -10
```

Comment: you need `df[] <- lapply(df, min_max)`

Comment: @akrun I got all `NaN` or `NA_real_` for my data frame

Comment: It returns 0 for `-10`

Comment: What is your expected output for the example showed

Comment: @akrun but in my own dataset, there are values equal to 0 too. it will mixed up 0 and missing values?

Comment: GarlicSTAT, I get no `NA` or `NaN` for that data and that function, perhaps you're using it differently than akrun suggested?

Comment: Ok, in that case, change the `-10` to a  positive value that is easier  i.e. 999

Comment: How about `function(x) ifelse(x<=0, NA, (x- min(x)) /(max(x)-min(x)))`?

Comment: add `na.rm=TRUE` to the `min` and `max` functions

Comment: or `function(x) replace(x, x>0, (x- min(x)) /(max(x)-min(x)))`?

Comment: @r2evans I tried the first way `function(x) ifelse(x<=0, NA, (x- min(x)) /(max(x)-` and got all NA values

Comment: @user20650 I tried both ways and got the error `Error in return((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)), na.rm = TRUE) :  multi-argument returns are not permitted`

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` is added to the `min` and `max` functions separately. See the dcos `?max` . ps this is assuming that you have set the -10 to NA as ouy mention in your function. pps you may find it eaier if you set -10 to NA when reading in the data; see `na.strings` argument

Comment: just realised... are you actually wanting to retain -10 in your data after scaling, instead of having them set to NA?

Comment: @user20650 it works! Thanks! I convert -10 to NA, and then convert NA back to -10 after scaling!

Comment: okay, good that you have got a solution, please consider writing it up -- and may be worth changing the title to something more relevant so it is easier to find